# Laravel 4 eloquent create doesn't work and fill does

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I want to create an instance of model called Property using method create with Input::all() as parameter. Input contains only fillable fields. When using create method laravel raise this exception:

```
alpha.ERROR: exception 'Illuminate\Database\QueryException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`propathai`.`properties`, CONSTRAINT `properties_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `properties` (`slug`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (, 2014-07-30 10:21:42, 2014-07-30 10:21:42))' in /home/ricardo/CHH/propathai/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:555
```

This exception is happening because insert query is not populated with all input params.

```
{"bedrooms":"4","title":"ricardo","room_type":"apartment","type":"rent","furnished":"fully_furnished","aging":"new","user_id":"3"}
```

I tried creating new Property object and using fill() method and it does work.

Code not working

```
public function store()
{
    $input = Input::all();
    $input['user_id'] = Auth::user()->id;

    $property = Property::create($input);

    return Response::json(array('success' => true, 'redirect' => '/dashboard/properties/'.$property->id.'/edit-details'));
}
```

Code working

```
public function store()
{
    $input = Input::all();
    $input['user_id'] = Auth::user()->id;

    $property = new Property;
    $property->fill($input);
    $property->save();

    return Response::json(array('success' => true, 'redirect' => '/dashboard/properties/'.$property->id.'/edit-details'));
}
```

Model

```
protected $guarded = array('id','services');

protected $fillable = array('user_id','bedrooms','title','room_type','type','furnished','aging');
```

If anyone knows why it's happening let me know please.

Thanks.

Comment: are you using any foreign keys??

Answer (score 0):

Your slug is not being filled.

```
 SQL: insert into `properties`
     (`slug`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (, 2014-07-30 10:21:42, 2014-07-30 10:21:42)
```

It may be one of those:
1- Your slug has a different name attribute on your input form.
2- It's not on your fillable array.
3- It's either empty, null or being filtered.
ex: to filter empty inputs I do:

```
$input = array_filter(Input::all(),'strlen');
```

By the way, the way you are doing this is not the nicest of ways. Check this out:
http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent
Click on "one to many"

What it would look like on your app?
Your model User

```
public function properties(){
    return $this->hasMany('Property');
}
```

Your model Property

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}
```

On your controller:

```
$user = Auth::user();
$input = Input::all();
$input['user_id'] = $user->id;
$user->properties()->create($input);
```

That would be a more 'Laravel' way to approach it.

Also, if you really wanna go PRO watch Laracasts by Jeffrey Way.
It's the best online resource for Laravel4 I've seen online.

Comment: change `belongsToMany` to `belongsTo`

Comment: And probably the method name to `user()` in the `Property` model.